# Restricting access to the backend of an Angular2 web application?

Tags: angular, web-applications, backend, restful-authentication, web-frontend

I'm going to develop a web application and I will most likely use Angular2 to do it. Since the application will need to store data on a server, I will need a backend that the web application can use to read/write from.

But how do I prevent others from using it from outside my web application? This doesn't seem possible? Any hardcoded tokens, API keys, etc. that I use in my front end will be visible to an attacker by viewing the source. Even if it can be made more difficult by obfuscating and minifying the JS source, it can never be made 100% secure this way, right?

So how can I create a backend that is usable by a web application front end, while at the same time restricting usage of it to *only my own* front end?

If it is not *generally* possible, would it be possible under some certain conditions, for instance if the web front end is loaded from the same server that the backend is running on? I'm thinking something along the lines of starting a server session when the front end script is initiated and dynamically generating the session ID for the front end? But I guess an attacker could easily create his own client anyway, he would just have to make sure that it loads the official client first and extract the session ID from it?

Comment: It's not all that grim (; Everyone could rob any bank if things were that bad. Start by requiring authentication to read/write to your server and use https. Ask google for "web application security", "content security policy" for more (:

Comment: This is an interesting question and I don't think you can. Basically, if you're using REST to load data to your frontend it means that this data is not sensitive data. You cannot stop someone from making REST call outside your frontend as much as you can't stop him from `curl https://yousite.com` and use a script to pickup the data that he need. However if you're dealing with sensitive data, you can pass tokens in the headers to check if you're sending the data to the identified user.

Comment: @Sasxa When you say "start by requiring authentication", you mean requiring authentication from the users of the web app? I've done some more research and it seems like people agree that it is practically impossible to do what I want to do and still have a backend that is reachable from a JS front end or mobile application since those can be reverse engineered, and that the next best thing is to instead rely on having users logging in to use the app (which is possible since the password isn't stored in the app)... would you agree with that?

Comment: Yea, a good start is keeping sensitive stuff (passwords, private keys...) on the server and never transmitting that over the wire. You can build on that and add additional levels of security.

Answer (score 0):

I'll share my personal experiences and tips with you.

It doesn't matter whether you're a black-hat hacker or a server admin, each piece of sensitive data is there in the stream in forms of **0**s and **1**s. Your best chance of keeping attackers from obtaining your data is to keep them restricted to your server. But, there is more to it than that..

### Important factors that influence data safety:

- **Backend safety**:

  - If your attackers can get to the data from the inside, all your efforts were in vain. Make sure there is no security flaw, so that they can't get access to a **root** terminal.
  - Your backend should handle all possible events that could occur on the client side. Someone may have sent malformed packets with a custom client and you should be prepared for that not to hand out sensitive data.
  - You should never send out more data than the bare minimum. Each unnecessary byte could open up new options for attackers.
- **Transportation layer safety**:

  - The byte stream of the packet can easily be intercepted. You should make sure that when they intercept it, they can't make out a word of it.
  - Use **SSL**. It's nowadays a must-have - provides you with an unbreakable (well, for the moment..) encryption. (provided of course, that the attackers won't get their hands on the private key - which leads us back to **backend safety**)
- **Frontend safety**:

  - No hardcoded keys, passwords or anything sensitive. It's visible to everyone.
  - Obfuscation and compression slows down reverse engineers, but it won't stop them. It's better to throw a code in their face that doesn't provide them with anything useful other than a framework.
- **Authentication**:

  - If you wish to hide something from average visitors, authentication is the way to go. I advise you against that you work out a solution on your own, there are already many frameworks and solutions that handle most bottlenecks that you would encounter. You should take a look at the JSON Web Tokens (JWT) - they support all active programming languages and are an open standard. (https://jwt.io)

It's crucial that you don't just think as a software engineering during development, but also as an attacker. You'll see, your coding will become more productive.